# JavaFX as a best practice using a common Base Controller

Tags: java, javafx-2

With JavaFX as a best practice, Is that fine to inherit all subsequent UI Controllers using a common BaseController or there will be some issues with it ? Thanks.

**BaseController**

```
public class BaseController implements Initializable {

  protected URL location;
  protected ResourceBundle rb;

  @Override 
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    this.location = location;
    this.resources = resources;
  }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController extends BaseController {

  // Use BaseController related inherited properties and methods  
}
```

Comment: At some point in time, implementation of `Initializable` interface is optional. You can create method named `initialize()` (put annotation `@FXML` if you want to keep it private) for initialization. For resource injection just create a field `@FXML private ResourceBundle resources` and FXMLLoader will populate it for you. If implementation of initialize method is the only reason you want to create BaseController, then I suggest you to stick to field auto injection

Comment: This will work except `FXMLLoader` wont inject private variables, call private initialize (annotated with `@FXML`) methods of the extended class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this approach with great success. The beauty of this solution was that each controller could encapsulate its own logic while also relying on common functionality I wanted to make available to all of my controllers.

I made my base controller abstract and implement `Initializable` and overrode the method in the subclass controller. Field injection was also handled on a subclass level.